# Django: Switched from single-settings file to multi-settings package, now I get: AttributeError: module 'core.settings' has no attribute '...'

Tags: python, django

I have a `settings` folder under `core` module with an `__init.py` and a `prod.py`, `dev.py`, `base.py`.

I added a variable to my `base.py`called `SITE_DIRECTORY`.

Then, I modify this variable in my `dev.py` which is set as my `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` through an ENV variable.

When I run the following code:

```
from core import settings

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^' + settings.SITE_DIRECTORY, include('frontend.urls'), name='frontend'),
    url(r'^' + settings.SITE_DIRECTORY + 'admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^' + settings.SITE_DIRECTORY + 'static/(?P<path>.*)$', views.serve),
]
```

I get:

> AttributeError: module 'core.settings' has no attribute
>   'SITE_DIRECTORY'

I have no idea why... Since I am now using a multi-settings package, do I have to change my import statement from `from core import settings` to something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your import statement `from core import settings` is wrong, it should be `from django.conf import settings`

Edit: You should read the documentation about how to use the settings in django: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/settings/#using-settings-in-python-code